# How to replace a similar code of different fields inside different classes in Java?

Tags: java, oop, for-loop

I am working on a Java project which has multiple classes which have instance variable of objects from other classes.  For example, BigClassA object has an array of SmallClassA objects; BigClassB object has an array of SmallClassB objects.

Eventhough BigClassA and BigClassB have completely different fields, they undergo similar operations with SmallClassA and SmallClassB.  Please see the code below:

```
public class BigClassA {
    // initialize all instance variables to 0
    double totValue     = 0;
    double totGainLoss  = 0;
    SmallClassA[] smallClassArray = new SmallClassA[2];

    public BigClassA(int i, int j) {

        smallClassArray[0] = new SmallClassA(i);
        smallClassArray[1] = new SmallClassA(j);

        for (int k; k<smallClassArray.length; k++) {
            totValue    += totSmallClassArray[k].getValue();
            totGainLoss += totSmallClassArray[k].getGainLoss();
        }
    }
}

public class BigClassB {
    // initialize all instance variables to 0
    double totFoo   = 0;
    double totBar   = 0;
    double totPvsNP = 0;
    SmallClassB[] smallClassArray = new SmallClassB[3];

    public BigClassB (int p, int q, int r) {

        smallClassArray[0]  = new SmallClassB(p);
        smallClassArray[1]  = new SmallClassB(q);
        smallClassArray[2]  = new SmallClassB(r);

        for (int k; k<smallClassArray.length; k++) {
            totFoo      += smallClassArray[k].getFoo();
            totBar      += smallClassArray[k].getBar();
            totPvsNP    += smallClassArray[k].getPvsNP();
        }       
    }
}
```

I think the for-loop's in both BigClassA and BigClassB has sufficiently similar characteristics and could be replaced with a common code.

Could anyone advise how to create an outside method that can work like the two for-loop's above without having to write a for-loop repetitively for each class?  Or perhaps some other ways to make the code more concise?  Thanks ahead for your help!

Comment: [This](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html) should help you.

Comment: +1. Is there something concise in Java8 to loop over an array and sum up getter values?

Comment: @MarounMaroun: Where would you introduce subclasses here?

Comment: Create a method with Object array as parameter and iterate through the object array. Check for instanceOf of each object with desired class and have if condition to get the values.

Comment: I would argue that this is a case of spurious refactoring. Any method you could come up with, you'd have to pass information about which field you wanted to update, and which methods you wanted to call, and passing all that information is more cumbersome than it is worth. Do not let a superficial resemblance in code lead you to refactor your way into a deep hole.

Comment: Thanks for all suggestions. I agree that what I was attempting to do might be considered spurious refractoring and would not make the code considerably more concise/readable, hence I'm probably leaving it alone for now.

Answer (score 1):

The code you give does not exhibits enough common parts to be worth such a refactoring, but there are ways to to it. As suggested by Maroun Maroun, you will have to go with inheritance, but there are many steps :

- identify a common interface or abstract class between `SmallClassA` and `SmallClassB`. In the best world, you will define both with the interface containing all methods with common signature, and the abstract class containing common code.
- identify a common generic abstract class between `BigClassA` and `BigClassB`, parameterized with `<T extends CommonSmallInterface>`
- make `class BigClassA extends CommonBigClass<SmallClassA>` and same for `B`

That way, you will avoid duplication of code at the price of a certain complexity.

Note : depending of how `SmallClassA` and `SmallClassB` are declared, their common interface and or superclass may also be generic.

Answer (score 0):

The standard way of abstracting similar behaviour is to use interfaces.
In your case you want to build a total some over all the elements of a list.

First create an interface

```
public interface Summable {
   double getSum(); 
}
```

Now implement that interface in SmallClassA and SmallClassB. This shifts most of the loop bodies to the specific classes e.g. for SmallClassA

```
public SmallClassA implements Summable{
    public double getSum() {
       return getValue() + getGainLoss();
    }
}
```

Now both your loops can be written as

```
for ( Summable summable : smallClassArray ) {
   total += summable.getSum();
}
```

You can also make this an external method.